# Join table with latest value, did not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to Join the `delivery` table with the `delivery_history` table's latest value. To do that, I wrote the following query, but that did not work:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM delivery as d
LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT * 
      FROM delivery_history 
      WHERE delivery_history.delivery_id = d.id 
      ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) h ON d.id = h.delivery_id 
WHERE h.delivery_status = 'Pending' GROUP BY d.id
```

**delivery table**

```
id | name  
1  | John
```

**delivery_history table**

```
id | delivery_id | delivery_status 
1  | 1           | Pending
2  | 1           | Invoiced
```

**Expected Result**

```
id | name | delivery_status 
1  | John | Invoiced
```

What is the issue with my query?

Comment: The latest what? `ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1`?? id?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: @Roy sorry it is a typing mistake, when i type the query on website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use logic like this:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM delivery d JOIN
     delivery_history dh
     ON dh.delivery_id = d.id JOIN
     (SELECT dh.delivery_id, MAX(dh.id) as max_id
      FROM delivery_history dh
      GROUP BY dh.delivery_id
     ) ddh
     ON ddh.delivery_id = dh.delivery_id AND ddh.max_id = dh.id
WHERE dh.delivery_status = 'Pending';
```

I changed the `LEFT JOIN` to a inner joins because you require a match for the `WHERE` condition.

EDIT:

If you only want the most recent status, it is probably more efficient to use a correlated subquery:

```
select d.*,
       (select dh.status
        from delivery_history dh
        where dh.delivery_id = d.id
        order by dh.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as latest_status
from delivery d
having latest_status = 'Pending';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [max](https://database.guide/max-find-the-maximum-value-in-a-column-in-mysql/)

```
SELECT d.id, max(h.id)
FROM delivery as d
LEFT JOIN delivery_history h ON h.delivery_id = d.id
WHERE h.delivery_status = 'Pending' 
GROUP BY d.id
```

Comment: from the schema one can assume that a delivery can be pending more than once, this does not take that into account